# How do I tell user that they've previously entered a letter with indexOf? JAVA

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char, indexof

When the user enters a letter it gets added to newString everytime. How do I return an error message if the user inputs the same letter more than once?

So for example user inputs: `a`, `b`, then `c`
then `newString = "abc"`

I just can't work out how to check whether the user has already entered a letter.
If they enter a again for example it should return an error message.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (newString.indexOf(input) != -1 ) {
    System.out.println( "Invalid" );
}
```

I imagined it would work because it is looking through `newString` for input and if it isn't there it will return `-1`.

Comment: Could you include the part where `newString` is set?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: newString = newString+ input;

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly I believe you can use the String `contains` method to check for a letter. It would be something like this:

```
if(newString.contains(letter))
```

Comment: `newString.indexOf(letter) != -1` works just fine. That is probably not the issue here.

Comment: FYI: the sourcecode for contains is `return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;`

Comment: Ok I have: if(newString.contains(input)) but it just returns it as if it isn't even checking if the string contains entered letter?

Comment: @user3096470 Please edit your original question and add all the code you are using for the class as it seems your issue might be more than just a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains`

```
String s = "helo";

if (s.contains(input)){
    // reject
}
```

or

```
if (!s.contains(input)){   // if string does not contain input
    s += input;            // concatenate to string
}
```

Comment: `contains()` uses `indexOf()` internally. The use of one over the other shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    String newString = "";
    System.out.print("Enter letter: ");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine().toUpperCase();
    while(true){
    if (newString.contains(input)) 
    { System.out.println( "Invalid" );}
    else
    {
        newString = newString+ input;
    }
    input = br.readLine().toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, it returns Invalid for every character entered?

Comment: what is the initial value of newString and what is manipulated value??

Comment: String newString= "";
newString= newString+ input;

Comment: its working fine here.. what have you entered as input??

Comment: are you appending input string before or after if condition??   >>'newString= newString+ input;'<<

Comment: String newString = "";

System.out.print("Enter letter: ");
String input = br.readLine().toUpperCase();

newString = newString+ input;

if (newString.indexOf(input) != -1 ) {
    System.out.println( "Invalid" );
}

Comment: hey change indexOf function to `.contains()`... use newString.contains(input) in if conditon..pls

Comment: Ok I have: if(newString.contains(input)) but it just returns it as if it isn't even checking if the string contains input?

Comment: It returns "Invalid" regardless of whether the letter is already in newString

Answer (score 0):

Each time a user enters a character, check that character against existing characters in the `String`.  So each time a user enters a character, do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newString.length(); i++) {
    if (newString.charAt(i) == input) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: When I compile with this, it says 'cannot find symbol - variable length'?

Comment: Sorry, it should be the method `length()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(newString.indexOf(letter) != -1){
      //Invalid             
}
```